# Default random 10 character string value for SQL Server column

Tags: sql-server, random, default-value, sql-server-2014

I have a column `rndm` in my table [guests]. Now, for the field `Default value or Binding` for the table, whenever a new row is inserted I want to automatically insert a 10-character random string into this column as the default value.

This random string may not contain special characters, only characters from `a-zA-Z0-9`. What is the best approach to achieve this?

To be clear: I don't want to generate this random string in my .NET code, I want it to be generated within SQL Server. And I want to paste this string generation directly into the field `Default value or Binding` for the table, so not a separate SQL statement. So for example like it works when pasting `getdate()` into the field  `Default value or Binding`.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expanding on what Deigo Garbar has already suggested.

If you want to use the expression as the default value in your table you would need to put this expression in a function.

But the problem is a UDF function will not allow you to use NEWID() function in it, it will complain about cannot use non-deterministic function in UDF bla bla....

A way around will be to create a view first which simply calls this expression then use that view inside your function and then use that function as Default value for your table.

**View**

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_Function_Base
AS
SELECT substring(replace(convert(varchar(100), NEWID()), '-', ''), 1, 10) AS Rand_Value
```

**Function**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_getRandom_Value()
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Rand_Value VARCHAR(10);
SELECT @Rand_Value = Rand_Value
FROM vw_Function_Base

  RETURN @Rand_Value;
END
```

Now you can use this function as default value in your table.

**Test**

```
CREATE TABLE SomeTest_Table
 ( ID        INT
 , RandValue VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT dbo.fn_getRandom_Value()
 )
GO

 INSERT INTO SomeTest_Table(ID)
 VALUES (1)
GO

 SELECT * FROM SomeTest_Table
```

**Important Note**

I am not convinced this Part of GUID value will always be unique, so be careful.

Comment: Thanks! However, when I paste this `fn_getRandom_Value()` or `fn_getRandom_Value` into the table field `Default Value or Binding`, SQL Server Management Studio replaces it directly with `N'fn_getRandom_Value'`...so making it a string. How can I prevent that?

Comment: write t-sql yourself dont expect Management Studio to do your work :)

Comment: Maybe I did not explain myself clearly :) I want to use a default value for this column without having to insert that value via the INSERT statement. Just like I would add `newid()` or `getdate()` in that field. I'll updated my post with a screenshot.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean, all I am saying is use t-sql to create or alter table definition , SSMS is to do only minor jobs. anyway enter the Default value as `([dbo].[fn_getRandom_Value]())`

Comment: Thanks. This almost works. It looks like your example only uses uppercase characters and no lowercase?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, NEWID()), '-', ''), 1, 10)
```

Comment: I can't paste your code directly into the field `Default value or Binding` of the table. How would I do that?

Comment: A short paragraph or even a sentence or two by way of explanation would have gone a long way into making this a great answer.

Comment: @Flo - try it without the SELECT (i.e. just the nested functions). The whole statement is mean as a sample T-SQL statement that will display the result in a query window.

Comment: I had to specify the length of the varchar, then this command worked for me; I only wanted 1 character in the random column: `substring(replace(CONVERT([varchar](36),newid()),'-',''),(1),(1))`